# Batch rename a bunch of files in diff directories

Tags: batch-file

I have a 100 or so sub directories with 4 or 5 files inside each sub directory.  One of these directories, for example, has the following files:

- John Matthews ID.jpg
- License John Matthews.pdf
- Certificate-John-Matthews.jpg

As you can see, the filenames are not in any uniform format.  What I would like to do is rename them like this:

- John_Matthews_ID.jpg
- John_Matthews_License.pdf  (note: name should be first then document
  type at end)
- John_Matthews_Certificate.jpg

So, what would be the best way to go about doing this quickly for all 100 sub-dirs?

Many thanks.

Comment: Quickly isn't the issue - writing an exception for every possible format is difficult when we have no access to the list to figure out which exceptions are needed.  To handle just the ones you have shown is easy.  As an after thought: John Matthews isn't the name in every filename, is it?

Comment: Hi, it isn't.  Basically, there are 100 different people with different names.  Exceptions are basically: people will have 3 names, 4 names, etc.  However, what is consistent, is the types in each filename.  So for example:  ID, License and Certificate.

Comment: Are all the ID files formatted as **FirstName LastName ID.jpg**, all the license files formatted as **License FirstName LastName.pdf**, and all the certificate files formatted as **Certificate-FirstName-LastName.jpg**?

Comment: No they are not sadly.  Sometimes ID is at the end, sometimes in beginning and same with certificate and license etc.

Comment: It could be largely converted fairly easily, if ID and License and Certificate are accurate and one is in every filename.  You may get an extra space or - at the beginning or end of the `name` portion.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set types=0
for %%t in (ID License Certificate) do (
   set /A types+=1
   set type[!types!]=%%t
)

for /D %%d in (*) do (
   cd "%%d"
   for /F "delims=" %%f in ('dir /A-D /B') do (
      set name=%%~Nf
      for /L %%i in (1,1,%types%) do for /F %%t in ("!type[%%i]!") do (
         if /I "!name:%%t=!" neq "!name!" (
            set "newName=!name:%%t=!"
            ECHO ren "!name!%%~Xf" "!newName: =_!_%%t%%~Xf"
         )
      )
   )
   cd ..
)
```

This Batch file needs to be adjusted accordingly with your reports on the results. The `ECHO` command just show the `REN` command that would be executed. Place the Batch file in the folder that cointain the 100 subdirectories and run it.

Comment: Will this will remove `id` from `John Kidd` ?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: This is tested.**

This is non-destructive and will merely create `temprename.bat.txt` file in the main folder for you to examine and see if it is doing what you need.

Rename it to `temprename.bat` and run it to commit the changes.

Run this in the main folder.

```
@echo off
del "temprename.bat.txt" 2>nul
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r %%a in (*.jpg *.pdf) do (
set "name=%%~na"
set "newname=!name:.=_!"
if "!newname:~-2!"=="ID" set "newname=!name:~0,-2!_ID"
if "!newname:~0,2!"=="ID" set "newname=!name:~2!_ID"
if not "!newname:License=!"=="!newname!" set "newname=!newname:License=!_License"
if not "!newname:Certificate=!"=="!newname!" set "newname=!newname:Certificate=!_Certificate"
set "newname=!newname: =_!"
set "newname=!newname:-=_!"
set "newname=!newname:__=_!"
set "newname=!newname:__=_!"
if  "!newname:~0,1!"=="_" set "newname=!newname:~1!"
if  "!newname:~0,1!"=="_" set "newname=!newname:~1!"

>>temprename.bat.txt echo ren "%%a" "!newname!%%~xa"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=c:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /s /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.*" '
 ) DO SET "name=%%~nxa"&SET "directory=%%~dpa"&CALL :process
)

GOTO :EOF
:: Process filename
:process
SET "namepart=%name:ID.jpg=%"
IF "%namepart%ID.jpg"=="%name%" CALL :CHANGE ID.jpg&GOTO :eof
SET "namepart=%name:License=%"
SET "namepart=%namepart:.pdf=%"
IF "License%namepart%.pdf"=="%name%" CALL :CHANGE License.jpg&GOTO :eof
SET "namepart=%name:Certificate=%"
SET "namepart=%namepart:.jpg=%"
IF "Certificate%namepart%.jpg"=="%name%" CALL :CHANGE Certificate.jpg&GOTO :eof
GOTO :eof

:CHANGE
:: Remove leading/trailing (space, dash)
IF "%namepart:~0,1%"==" " set "namepart=%namepart:~1%"
IF "%namepart:~-1%"==" "  set "namepart=%namepart:~0,-1%"
IF "%namepart:~0,1%"=="-" set "namepart=%namepart:~1%"
IF "%namepart:~-1%"=="-"  set "namepart=%namepart:~0,-1%"
:: Now change remaining (space,dash) to underscore
SET "namepart=%namepart: =_%
SET "namepart=%namepart:-=_%
ECHO REN "%directory%%name%" "%namepart% %1"
GOTO :eof
```

Should do the job. Of course, Ms. Meredith-Rebecca Cholmondley-Ffytch may disapprove...

The required commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. After you've verified that the commands are correct, change `ECHO REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

---

Revision given further information...

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=c:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /s /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO SET "name=%%~nxa"&SET "directory=%%~dpa"&CALL :process
)

GOTO :EOF
:: Process filename
:process
FOR %%f IN (ID.jpg License.pdf Certificate.jpg) DO (CALL :extractname %%~nf %%~xf)
GOTO :eof

:extractname
CALL SET "namepart=%%name:%1%2=%%"
IF "%namepart%%1%2"=="%name%" CALL :CHANGE %1%2&GOTO :eof
CALL SET "namepart=%%name:%1=%%"
CALL SET "namepart=%%namepart:%2=%%"
IF "%1%namepart%%2"=="%name%" CALL :CHANGE %1%2&GOTO :eof
CALL :length %1
SET /a $p1=%length%
CALL :length %2
CALL SET "namepart=%%name:~%$p1%,-%length%%%"
IF "%1%namepart%%2"=="%name%" CALL :CHANGE %1%2&GOTO :eof
GOTO :eof

:length
SET /a length=0
SET "$1=%1"
:lengthl
IF NOT DEFINED $1 GOTO :EOF
SET /a length+=1
SET "$1=%$1:~1%"
GOTO lengthl

:CHANGE
:: Remove leading/trailing (space, dash)
IF "%namepart:~0,1%"==" " set "namepart=%namepart:~1%"
IF "%namepart:~-1%"==" "  set "namepart=%namepart:~0,-1%"
IF "%namepart:~0,1%"=="-" set "namepart=%namepart:~1%"
IF "%namepart:~-1%"=="-"  set "namepart=%namepart:~0,-1%"
:: Now change remaining (space,dash) to underscore
SET "namepart=%namepart: =_%
SET "namepart=%namepart:-=_%
ECHO REN "%directory%%name%" "%namepart% %1"
GOTO :eof
```

Re-edited to suit foxidrive's friend Midge and the crew...

Test dirlist:

```
ABCDEFGH123.pdf
Certificate Ida Buttrose.jpg
Certificate Midge Ridley.jpg
Certificate Stupid Cupid.jpg
Certificate-Ida Buttrose.jpg
Certificate-John-Matthews.jpg
Certificate-Midge Ridley.jpg
ID Ida Buttrose.jpg
ID Midge Ridley.jpg
ID Stupid Cupid.jpg
Ida Buttrose Certificate.jpg
Ida Buttrose ID.jpg
Ida Buttrose License.pdf
John Matthews ID.jpg
License Ida Buttrose.pdf
License John Matthews.pdf
License Midge Ridley.pdf
License Stupid Cupid.pdf
Midge Ridley Certificate.jpg
Midge Ridley ID.jpg
Midge Ridley License.pdf
oldname.zip
Stupid Cupid Certificate.jpg
Stupid Cupid ID.jpg
Stupid Cupid License.pdf
```

Test result:

```
REN "c:\sourcedir\Certificate Ida Buttrose.jpg" "Ida_Buttrose Certificate.jpg"
REN "c:\sourcedir\Certificate Midge Ridley.jpg" "Midge_Ridley Certificate.jpg"
REN "c:\sourcedir\Certificate Stupid Cupid.jpg" "Stupid_Cupid Certificate.jpg"
REN "c:\sourcedir\Certificate-Ida Buttrose.jpg" "Ida_Buttrose Certificate.jpg"
REN "c:\sourcedir\Certificate-John-Matthews.jpg" "John_Matthews Certificate.jpg"
REN "c:\sourcedir\Certificate-Midge Ridley.jpg" "Midge_Ridley Certificate.jpg"
REN "c:\sourcedir\ID Ida Buttrose.jpg" "Ida_Buttrose ID.jpg"
REN "c:\sourcedir\ID Midge Ridley.jpg" "Midge_Ridley ID.jpg"
REN "c:\sourcedir\ID Stupid Cupid.jpg" "Stupid_Cupid ID.jpg"
REN "c:\sourcedir\Ida Buttrose Certificate.jpg" "Ida_Buttrose Certificate.jpg"
REN "c:\sourcedir\Ida Buttrose ID.jpg" "Ida_Buttrose ID.jpg"
REN "c:\sourcedir\Ida Buttrose License.pdf" "Ida_Buttrose License.pdf"
REN "c:\sourcedir\John Matthews ID.jpg" "John_Matthews ID.jpg"
REN "c:\sourcedir\License Ida Buttrose.pdf" "Ida_Buttrose License.pdf"
REN "c:\sourcedir\License John Matthews.pdf" "John_Matthews License.pdf"
REN "c:\sourcedir\License Midge Ridley.pdf" "Midge_Ridley License.pdf"
REN "c:\sourcedir\License Stupid Cupid.pdf" "Stupid_Cupid License.pdf"
REN "c:\sourcedir\Midge Ridley Certificate.jpg" "Midge_Ridley Certificate.jpg"
REN "c:\sourcedir\Midge Ridley ID.jpg" "Midge_Ridley ID.jpg"
REN "c:\sourcedir\Midge Ridley License.pdf" "Midge_Ridley License.pdf"
REN "c:\sourcedir\Stupid Cupid Certificate.jpg" "Stupid_Cupid Certificate.jpg"
REN "c:\sourcedir\Stupid Cupid ID.jpg" "Stupid_Cupid ID.jpg"
REN "c:\sourcedir\Stupid Cupid License.pdf" "Stupid_Cupid License.pdf"
```

Comment: Will this handle `Midge Ridley` with `id` in the name?  Does it support `ID` at the start of the filename?